# Error: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (2,) and (2, 150000, 1)

Tags: python

So I am trying to plot some data. But I am getting this error:

```
x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (2,) and (2, 150000, 1)
```

My data is the second matrix with three elements. There are 150000 data points and each data point is being plotted separtely whereas I want to capture all the data points in one line. How can I fix this error? Can I use the 3 dimension which is one and plot (2,1) to capture all the data in one line?

Comment: Could you please show the code you are using to make the plot? And describe the data?

Comment: filteredData = freqs(b, a, np.ravel(signala)))
plt.plot(filteredData) where b and a are one variable and signal a is my data which is (2,150000,1)